Find the largest possible value of S(n).

I am not sure what the questions means: I think we must be able to choose the values of the n real numbers, or else the question is unapproachable.
My initial thought was to pick the n numbers to be 0 and 1 alternating, as this would provide the maximum absolute value as each number is in the closed interval [0, 1]. I am not sure how to phrase this argument rigorously, if it is true at all.
Assuming the n real numbers are alternating 0 and 1, then just looking at the pattern, I think S(n) = ⌊n/2⌋·⌈n/2⌉ - I'm not sure how to prove this, strong induction doesn't seem to work.
Any tips would be helpful! Thanks.

Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1631463/42969

For a pithy description, suppose we have a set of $n$ points from the interval $[0,1]$. Let $S(n)$ be the sum of the distances between each pair of points in this set. What is the maximum value of $S(n)$?

Suppose n is even, then n/2 would the max distance? If n is odd, we have (n-1)/2+(n+1)/2? So should we halve that since i =< j?
